# regex to find this pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have below content in file

```
/** 
 some text
 text1 
 text2
 some text
**/
```

I want to check if "text1" or "text2" is contained in between  /**  **/ as mentioned in above example.

I tried  below code

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("//*/*.*?text1.*?/*/*/");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(fileAsString);
  while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("match found");
  }
```

but it has two shortcomings . These are :-

1) It checks for text1  in between /** text1 **/ but does not work when text1 is in next line

2)I am not sure how to check  any of the two strings i.e "text1" or "text2" in this regex?

Comment: For (2), use text(1|2) instead of text1. More generally, (A|B) matches either A or B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\*\\*.*?(?:text1|text2).*?\\*\\*/", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

1. `Pattern.DOTALL` is required to make sure to match text spanning multiple lines
2. `*` needs to be escaped using `\\*`
3. `(?:text1|text2)` is a non capturing alternation, needed to match `text1` or `text2`.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. Is there a way in regex itself to match text spanning multiple lines instead of using Patter.DOTALL

Comment: Got it i can do it with (?s)

Comment: i think  Pattern.compile("/\\*\\*.*?text1|text2.*?\\*\\*/", Pattern.DOTALL) will also work fine . why did you use (?:text1|text2) instead of just text1|text2 ?

Comment: It is better to enclose alternation in a bracket otherwise `|` is effective for `/\*\*.*?text1` instead of just `text1`. I used `(?:..)` for non capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will ensure that you are always inside the comment part when `text1` or `text2` is found. To do that I repeat a group that can not match the comment end `**/`: `(?>[^*]|\\*(?!\\*/))*`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\Q/**\\E"
                          + "(?>[^*]|\\*(?!\\*/))*?"
                          + "(?:text1|text2)"
                          + "(?>[^*]|\\*(?!\\*/))*"
                          + "\\Q**/\\E");
```

Answer (score -1):

do you have to use a regex? would String.indexOf be a possible way to tell if the text is contained? You can substring the inner string between the /* */ tags and then do an indexOf